# Customize Spring Data Rest projection

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have an entity with `Date` field:

```
@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) // this annotation impacts on result
@JsonFormat(pattern = DATE_FORMAT)
@Column(name = "my_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Date myTime;
```

I have a projection with the field:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
String getMyTime();
```

This is my java code:

```
@Autowired
private ProjectionFactory projectionFactory;

....
public PagedResources<Resource<MyEntityProjection>> transform(final Page<MyEntity> page) {
    return assembler.toResource(page, entity -> {
        final MyEntityProjection projected = projectionFactory.createProjection(MyEntityProjection.class, entity);
        return new Resource<>(projected, <some links>);
    });
}
```

When I try to create a projection for this entity in java code, I receive following format in JSON:

```
"myTime": "2017-07-27"
```

How to fix it to receive dates in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution:

Just add annotation to your field in Projection interface;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
Date getMyDate();
```